# In Pdf, the fields on later pages, on clicking reflect the values of first page

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I am generating a pdf from C# .net. The pdf has a page, which is dynamically added with different values. i.e. the page is same and repeatedly added with  different values on every page.
The issue that I am facing is, when on 2nd or later pages, I click on any field it reflects the value of first page field. 
[image: First Page field]

[image: Second Page field]
[image: Second Page field on clicking]

This occurs on click only.
Please suggest as to why this is happening? How can I resolve it?
Is it because I am dynamically repeating and adding the pages or this issue is occuring due to some other reason?

Comment: Your description only contains enough information to start guessing, not more. I would guess you merged multiple copies of the same AcroForm form. Thus, the matching fields on the multiple copies have the same field name respectively. Fields with the same name are considered visualizations of the same abstract field and, therefore, have the same value. Of this is the case, you have torename fields before merging

Comment: Thanks, I guessed it but was not sure enough. It now cleared up my doubt.